# why does the collision between two rectangles not work?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection, game-physics

I would like to understand one thing , below I saw that a collision between two rectangles works .

create method:

```
//nave
    spaceShip = new Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("rocket.png")),98,154));
    spaceShip.setOrigin(spaceShip.getWidth()/2, spaceShip.getHeight()/2);
    spaceShip.setBounds(spaceShip.getX(),spaceShip.getY(),spaceShip.getWidth(),spaceShip.getHeight());
    spaceShip.setZIndex(3);

    //meteora
    meteora = new Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("planet.png")),128,128));
    meteora.setOrigin(meteora.getWidth()/2,meteora.getHeight()/2);
    meteora.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    meteora.setBounds(meteora.getX(),meteora.getY(),meteora.getWidth(),meteora.getHeight());
    meteora.setZIndex(3);
```

Render method:

```
rect1 = new Rectangle(spaceShip.getX(),spaceShip.getY(),spaceShip.getWidth(),spaceShip.getHeight());
    rect2 = new Rectangle(meteora.getX(),meteora.getY(),meteora.getWidth(),meteora.getHeight());

    if(Intersector.overlaps(rect1,rect2)){
        System.out.println("collision");
    }
```

Now , my question is :
as I can see collisions with dynamic objects .
Let me explain, there will be different now created in a random time .
So how can I tell if a collision occurs with one of these objects and understand what it is .
Rectangle has no method .setName , I wanted to use this to figure out which object my ship touched .

Can anyone recommend a solution ?

Thank You

EDIT 
add Image object

```
    meteora = new Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("planet.png")), 128, 128));
    meteora.setOrigin(meteora.getWidth() / 2, meteora.getHeight() / 2);
    meteora.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, 100);
    meteora.setZIndex(3);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(meteora.getX(),meteora.getY(),meteora.getWidth(),meteora.getHeight());
    rectangles.add(rect);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the question is, but in answer to what I think you are getting at:

Typically you would want to add all the new randomly created rectangles to a collection of rectangles, then you can iterate through this collection to check for collisions:

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();  // a field in your class

// inside the method to create random rectangles
Rectangle tmp = new Rectangle(1,2,3,4);     
rectangles.add(tmp);  

// inside the method to check for collisions
for(Rectangle rect : rectangles) {
  if(Intersector.overlaps(rect, shipRect) {
     System.out.println("collision");
  }
}
```

Note that your `rect1` for your ship's bounds should be saved as a field (`shipRect` in this example) as well so that you can refer back to it at any time

Comment: This code only works if I my ship goes over the origin of the creation of the rectangles and not on Image more .
Can you tell me why ?

Comment: i have edit my question with my dynamic generation of actor..can you see the code please ? Thanks

Comment: perhaps I understand, the rectangle does not follow the sprite , because it is the sprite that is generated automatically , and it , moving loses rect .
that's right? is there a solution ?

Comment: How is your sprite getting updated? Wherever this happens, you will need to update its bounds as well. I think there may will be some code structure problems though. Try having a look at the book Beginning Android Games, it explains everything well and is written by the libgdx guys